# Writing range from Excel to Outlook body

Tags: vb.net, excel, outlook

I need to take a range from Excel and have it paste over into an Outlook email message. The issue being when I do this it just pastes the text and not the table. Below is the code. I tried picture, but I don't want to have to embed it, don't understand why it won't just paste it like any other time I copy an image. I am working with Office 2013.

```
    Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Dim objexcel As New Excel.Application
    Dim objWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim Range As Excel.Range

    objexcel.DisplayAlerts = False


    objWorkbook = objexcel.Workbooks.Open("c://Derp")

    objWorksheet = CType(objWorkbook.Worksheets.Item("Sheet1"), Excel.Worksheet)
    objWorksheet.Unprotect()

    objWorksheet.Cells(2, 1).value = txtTravEmails.Text
    objWorksheet.Cells(2, 4).value = Txttravemdate.Text
    objWorksheet.Cells(3, 1).value = txtTravUnread.Text
    objWorksheet.Cells(3, 4).value = Txttravundate.Text
    objWorksheet.Cells(6, 1).value = txtITweb.Text
    objWorksheet.Cells(6, 4).value = Txtwebdate.Text
    objWorksheet.Cells(7, 1).value = txtITAPI.Text
    objWorksheet.Cells(7, 4).value = Txtapidate.Text
    objWorksheet.Cells(8, 1).value = txtITpend.Text
    objWorksheet.Cells(8, 4).value = Txtpenddate.Text
    'objWorksheet.Range("A1:D9").CopyPicture()
    Range = objWorksheet.Range("A1:D9")
    Range.Copy()

    If Chkmorning.Checked = True Then
        Dim Email As New Email_Templates
        Email.Morning()
    ElseIf Chkmid.Checked = True Then
        Dim Email As New Email_Templates
        Email.Mid()
    ElseIf Chkevening.Checked = True Then
        Dim Email As New Email_Templates
        Email.Evening()
    ElseIf Chkmidnight.Checked = True Then
        Dim Email As New Email_Templates
        Email.Midnight()
    End If

    objWorkbook.Save()
    objWorkbook.Close()
    objexcel.Quit()


End Sub

Public Sub Morning()

    Dim Morning As String = "<html>" +
                "<HEAD>" +
                "<TITLE>Email</TITLE>" +
                "</HEAD>" +
                "<BODY>" +
                "<font face=Calibri>" +
                "<b> This is the morning report sent at " + DateAndTime.Now.ToShortTimeString + " EST! " +
                "<br><br>" + Clipboard.GetText +
                    "</font>" +
                    "</BODY>" +
                    "</HTML>"

    mail.Recipients.Add("derp@derp.com")
    mail.BCC = ""

    mail.Subject =  Date.Now.ToShortDateString
    mail.HTMLBody = Morning
    'mail.Body = "This is the morning report sent at " & DateAndTime.Now.ToShortTimeString & " EST!" & vbNewLine & Clipboard.GetText

    mail.Display()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the format that you want off the clipboard data.

```
Dim Morning As String = "<html>" +
            "<HEAD>" +
            "<TITLE>Email</TITLE>" +
            "</HEAD>" +
            "<BODY>" +
            "<font face=Calibri>" +
            "<b> This is the morning report sent at " + DateAndTime.Now.ToShortTimeString + " EST! " +
            "<br><br>" + Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html) +
                "</font>" +
                "</BODY>" +
                "</HTML>"
```

The [Clipboard.GetText method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.gettext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has an optional *format* parameter using the [TextDataFormat constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/944ft9kf(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Now its not copying, but I think it was doing that before. Am I doing the copying correct?

Comment: Ok got it to copy by moving the if statement before I clear the excel memory, so the html "works" but it pastes over the file path and some other nonsense before it.

Answer (score 0):

Added the following to the morning sub

```
Dim Report As String

Report = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html)

Report = Report.Substring(Report.IndexOf("<html"))
```

and changed

```
mail.HTMLBody = Midnight & Report
```

Removed the sourceurl information before the pasted table